# onhashchange with IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, hashchange

I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if ("onhashchange" in window) {
      alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
   }
   function test(){
  alert("hash has changed = " + window.location.hash)
   }
   window.onhashchange =test;
}
```

I click a link that changes the hash and in all other browsers I get the alert in `test`

However in IE I get the first alert saying it supports onhashchange but then when the hash changes nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example on the MSDN doc [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc891506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Basically, I removed all the extra "map" stuff on their page and the only difference between theirs and your example is that they include the following meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

I added this to the head tag in your example and it worked fine.

This meta-tag basically says to run the page as if it were in IE 8 and not IE 9 (which is still in beta).

For more information on this meta-tag read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

See this: [link](https://gist.github.com/1599740)

> Does the browser support window.onhashchange?

Note that IE8 running in IE7 compatibility mode reports true for 'onhashchange' in window, 
even though the event isn't supported, so also test `document.documentMode`.

```
var docmode = document.documentMode;
if ('onhashchange' in window && (docmode === undefined || docmode > 7 )) {
    window.onhashchange = checkHash;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new hashchange event in HTML5 is supported by all current browsers; no need to fool your browser into thinking it's IE8.

This code works in IE 9, FF 5, Safari 5, and Chrome 12 on Win 7:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            window.onhashchange = doThisWhenTheHashChanges;

            function changeTheHash()
            {
                var newHashValue = document.getElementById("newHashInput").value;
                var currentLocation = window.location.pathname;
                window.location.hash = newHashValue;
            }

            function doThisWhenTheHashChanges()
            {
                alert("The hash has changed!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Hash Change Test</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="newHashInput" autofocus>
            <input type="button" value="Set" onclick="changeTheHash()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```