# Do something when browser back button is pressed when there is a hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, fragment-identifier

I am trying to get an alert to fire when I press back to get to a page from a hash. I'm using the following code

```
if(window.location.hash) {
} else {
    alert('test');
}
```

If I'm at http://someurl.com/#somehash and I press the browser back button to get back to http://someurl.com/ the alert doesn't fire.

Is there any way to make that work, or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908172/jquery-up-to-date-hash-change-listener) is you question already answered.

It boils down to using a listener:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
  console.log('hash changed');
}
```