# JavaScript function doesn't execute in IE (called onhashchange), works in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, hashchange

This site: http://jcorps.org/jsuite WORKS in Chrome, changing the content based on a HASH CHANGE, and IE9 seems to be handling the onHashChange, but...

IE9 doesn't execute the "UpdatePage()" function at all or produce an error message of any kind in IE's developer/debug console, so I cannot see where it's "breaking". Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Ari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a [doctype](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) on your page, so IE9 renders it in quirks mode, which does not support the hashchange event.  Adding a proper doctype will allow IE9 to render your page in the proper mode, enabling the hashchange event.

Also see this similar question: [onhashchange with IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984319/onhashchange-with-ie-9)

Comment: Wow. Thanks @Waxen. HOWEVER, now it's broken in Firefox. (Works in IE and Chrome). Thoughts?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me in FF18.  What version are you on?

Comment: Ah, wow. It was FF11, never updated, I guess. Just did. Should I be concerned about FF11 users not being able to use the site? (Or am I rare oddity?)

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about old versions of FF; I'd be more concerned about people still using IE7, though not concerned enough to do anything about it.  Having said that, looking at the [MDN hashchange documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange#Browser_compatibility), FF has supported that event since 3.6, so I'm not sure why FF11 didn't work for you.